# What should i do with google oauth response?

Tags: oauth, google-oauth, google-authentication

So, i've got this response from google upon authentication:

```
{
  "user": {
    "id": "116807551237969746774",
    "email": "123456@gmail.com",
    "verified_email": true,
    "name": "John Doe",
    "given_name": "John",
    "family_name": "Doe",
    "picture": "https:\/\/lh3.googleusercontent.com\/-XdUIqdMkCWA\/AAAAAAAAAAI\/AAAAAAAAAAA\/4252ldubv5M\/photo.jpg",
    "locale": "en"
  },
  "credentials": {
    "access_token": "ya29.GlsSBIA_hMKZIDE_wqJAJS0vrHD_Wd2HfwRTTvLISv0i1uFICCqz4JdEZcL09mFFlGdt71D9pW80SLShHgyeSOZgnWcL5piL5m0jYo1TMU6o0fDLnqGAWm6BY-Wl",
    "token_type": "Bearer",
    "expires_in": 3600,
    "refresh_token": "1\/az_TmhPRaYG5NDH6L9gBeNo6STOD9EbTt1VkkBmp3IQ",
    "id_token": "eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IjBlNmExN2I2YjU4MGIzNTFmMGQ5YmEzMzY2YTU0Y2U1NmViOWIxN2UifQ.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.BHv5BP3ZsagvunfMzGLwmxkBdtoRocPa_PXdq2lrd4D9BoFGkK06eJVbNNbcPOFdAMba3V5lIIG_L499gIy3TTz_PIHBPi6DMSp6uyfkCwf2n-PspZtTbTRlUm5ZvRdAyPEEyLLkWllKkMsRk-Nwp3vhyOLnExzH7SXiEefU4kaXXCpjsHV3GvZ-yhrmNlicEY3TPLwI-tl_lydXTBXRRiPZBGWjHK75hqvQzUktC2Flimd7JnCLhF0FOS3yFKc5D11WPKMOO4YkIQDbBrKY64vyxQAd-Zb2KfvXZi6Dorq7IJF6sK2GAfI3edSaoMZBMa0-x2V7FuFIBLtTgGRnsw"
  }
}
```

I haven't found documentation on what should i do with `credentials` part of this response? What should i use for user identification? What should be saved as token on client side (ios/android app) in order to revive the session? What does `expires_in: 3600` means and what should i do about it? What does `token_type: Bearer` means and why do i need it? etc.

---

Thank you, @pinoyyid for clarifications!
The main thing i was looking for is this:

On server side get `access_token` property from `credentials` and verify it, using this url

```
https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo?access_token={your access_token}
```

Do whatever you want with the rest of the provided data.

Personally, i'll prefer to generate own token, save it on client side and use it to revive user's session (to verify his identity). Once token is lost for whatever reason, user just will go through the whole process again.

Answer (score 3):

**what should i do with credentials part of this response?**

Rejoice, for you have done the hard part.

**What should i use for user identification?**

Anything you like, or nothing at all. It depends on your app's use case.

**What should be saved as token on client side (ios/android app) in order to revive the session?**

The Refresh Token. Note that "revive the session" is wrong terminology. In OAuth/REST, there are no sessions.

**What does expires_in: 3600 means and what should i do about it?**

It is saying that the Access Token will expire in 1 hour (3600 seconds). What you should do is use the Refresh Token to acquire a new Access Token by POSTing it as described https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer#offline

**What does token_type: Bearer means?**

It means the Access Token should be placed in an HTTP Authorization header whenever you try to access a Google API. Eg `Authorization: "Bearer aaaaaaa"` where aaaaaa is the Access Token.

**and why do i need it?**

To prove to Google that your app has been given permission to access a Google resource (eg. a file in Drive) by the owner of that resource.